# How do I get type decimal from an XML byte stream from SSRS?

Tags: xml, vb.net, reporting-services, xml-serialization, ssrs-2008

How do I get type decimal from an XML byte stream from SSRS? In other words, how do I also get the XML schema or some other information that defines the cell data types?

I am getting an SSRS report in XML format as byte stream.  The problem is that all cells in the datatables are type string.  I need the decimals as decimal.  How do I do that?  Is it an SSRS setting or a VB function? There is a large amount of data returned in many datatables within the dataset. I am using Dataset.ReadXml().

All of the expressions in cells are formatted as such:

```
=Format(Fields!Sales.Value, "N1")
```

Here’s my VB snippet:

```
    result = rs.Render(format, devInfo, extension, _
       encoding, mimeType, warnings, streamIDs)

    execInfo = rs.GetExecutionInfo()

    Dim bytes() As Byte = result
    Dim s As New System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes)
    dsDevData.ReadXml(s)
```

Comment: The problem is either in your dataset.writeXML, you need to include the schema information parameter to tell it to include the schema. Or, if you are not controling that, see what the query is doing and where the data is coming from. Perhaps the query or stored propcedure is converting it to strings. NOTE: If you are getting the dataset and sending it to this code, change the serialization type to binary, instead of the default XML. Much smaller and faster.

Comment: Awesome Steve, thanks. It is XML output from SSRS, so I'll see what I can do about getting the schema. I'm already getting it as a byte stream.